# Android Studio 3.3.2 annotation processor

Tags: android-studio, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I just upgrade my Android Studio to 3.3.2 and installed the Lombok plugin.
I need to re-activate my annotation processor, but the option doesn't appear to be there anymore.

So where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to go to File > other settings > Preferences for New Projects

it should be available there

Comment: Yeah ok, but I have my existing project, I don't want to create a new project. Shouldn't it be possible to add to my existing project?

Comment: Then after try to reimport the Project

Comment: It works, despite the error message remaining in the event log. Accept in a minute

Comment: I had the same in a Project who used the lombok plugin, it's a nightmare

Comment: This seems to exclusively be an issue with Android Studio though - these settings are present in IntelliJ. I'm guessing it's intentional, but it's slightly horrible design.